# Why Elastic search is showing up only first 50 lines(events) in browser?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am publishing events from Logstash to elastic search and console.
After clicking on */_plugin/head/-->Browser tab-->created_index able to see only first 50 lines where as in console all lines i am seeing.

Why this strange behavior ? Please can one suggest ?

Comment: It's a default from the head plugin. (by default elasticsearch returns only 10 results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better enough to modify \plugins\head_site\dist\app.js file in 846 line.No need to look for \plugins\head_site_site\app.js as it is hidden file.

Answer (score 1):

It's a default from the head plugin. (by default elasticsearch returns only 10 results).

You can change that in the source of the plugin (but I have not tested if there's side effects):
In elasticsearch/plugins/head/_site/app.js:

```
data.Query = ux.Observable.extend({
        defaults: {
            cluster: null,  // (required) instanceof app.services.Cluster
            size: 50        // size of pages to return
```

You can replace 50 by whatever number you want.

Comment: Thank you very much.Can we set to any integer or is there any limit ?

Comment: @feelgoodandprogramming The default limit is 10,000. More info here : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/search-request-from-size.html

Comment: Hi @Yeikel Thank you very much.